# Setting property volume of HTML5 audio with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I am trying to set the volume of an audio element with jQuery.

```
<audio class="audio" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" src="All_Right.mp3"></audio>
```

So i am selecting the audio tag and setting the volume like so:

```
$('.audio').prop(volume, 0.1);
```

But i got Uncaught Reference Error: `volume is not defined`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your line:

```
$('.audio').prop(volume, 0.1);
```

You are passing `volume` as a variable not as a string.  You do not have a variable named `volume`, which is why you are receiving the error about it not being defined.  Try changing it to:

```
$('.audio').prop("volume", 0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
$('.audio').volume = 0.1;
```